# Select menu keystroke

Tags: interface, customization, shortcut

I was trying to look for the select menu shortcut from the settings to no avail. The reason for this is I want to improve my workflow and adding select menu to a simple simple keystroke would improve it a lot.

Now I know it's possible add hotkeys for individual actions, but I tend to use a lot of the tools available in the select menu and it would be great to have them all under a shortcut accessible menu. Similar to how one can bring up the Specials contextual with the W button.

tl;dr: How can I bring this up with a keystroke?

[image: Select menu]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Open up the **User Preferences Window** and switch to **Input** tab
2. Expand the **3D View -> 3D View (Global)** keymap and add a new item (Scroll down and click the **Add New** button.
3. Enter the operator name as **wm.call_menu**
4. Enter the operator parameter **Name** as **VIEW3D_MT_view**
5. Assign your desired hotkey.
6. Save user preferences (Click on the **Save User Settings** button.

Comment: This was a bit more clearer than the other answer, thanks! Worth noting that operator parameter name can be the name of any sub-menu.

Answer (score 3):

add a hotkey, and for the action type `wm.call_menu`. In the 'name' field that appears, put the text that pops up when you hover over the menu (it is case sensitive).

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following to call submenus from select menu.I hope this helps u guys :)

```
VIEW3D_MT_select_object
VIEW3D_MT_select_object_more_less
VIEW3D_MT_select_pose
VIEW3D_MT_select_pose_more_less
VIEW3D_MT_select_particle
VIEW3D_MT_edit_mesh
VIEW3D_MT_edit_mesh_select_similar
VIEW3D_MT_edit_mesh_select_by_trait
VIEW3D_MT_edit_mesh_select_more_less
VIEW3D_MT_select_edit_mesh
VIEW3D_MT_select_edit_curve
VIEW3D_MT_select_edit_surface
VIEW3D_MT_select_edit_text
VIEW3D_MT_select_edit_metaball
VIEW3D_MT_edit_lattice_context_menu
VIEW3D_MT_select_edit_lattice
VIEW3D_MT_select_edit_armature
VIEW3D_MT_select_gpencil
VIEW3D_MT_select_paint_mask
VIEW3D_MT_select_paint_mask_vertex
```